# Convergence of upper order statistic

Tags: convergence-divergence, order-statistics

Consider a sequence of iid standard uniform random variables $U_1,\ldots, U_n$  and their order statistics $U_{1,n}\leq \ldots \leq U_{n,n}$.

I am led to believe that 
\begin{equation*}
1- U_{n,n} = O\mathopen{}\left(\frac{\log\log n}n\right), \quad \text{a.s. for }n\to \infty,
\end{equation*}
where $O(\cdot)$ is the notation for a [big-$O$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), i.e. supposedly (as I understand it),
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(1-U_{n,n})}{\log\log n} < \infty \quad \text{a.s.}
\end{equation*}

How do I go about to prove this?

---

Backstory:

In an article<sup>1</sup> I am reading they mention that the above result holds by by Kiefer (1972), however, I cannot find that citation in their bibliography and searching for it ([attempt 1](https://www.google.dk/search?q=kiefer%201972&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=mLzCWNftCsHM6ATh6bfIDQ), [attempt 2](https://www.google.dk/search?q=kiefer%201972&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=mLzCWNftCsHM6ATh6bfIDQ#safe=off&q=kiefer%201972%20order%20statistics&*), [attempt 3](https://www.google.dk/search?q=kiefer%201972&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr&ei=mLzCWNftCsHM6ATh6bfIDQ#safe=off&q=kiefer%201972%20bootstrap&*)), I at maximum find Amazon/Google books results that also refer to the citation but I have not had any luck at having page reviews of their bibliographies. As I cannot find a reference to see the proof and because I would like to use the result, I would like to prove it.

---

<sup>1. Paul Deheuvels, David M. Mason, and Galen R. Shorack. Some results on the
influence of extremes on the bootstrap. *Annales de l’I.H.P. Probabilités et
statistiques*, 29(1):83–103, 1993. http://eudml.org/doc/77452</sup>

Comment: Look at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200514094

Comment: There it is! Thank you, @NCh.

Comment: After having read Wellner (1972) where the claim is (supposedly) proven, I am, unfortunately, still at a loss. I cannot see how they prove the above result.

Comment: Do you mean Kiefer (1972), not Wellner? If yes, the above result is at Theorem 2, p.235. For $k=1$, $nZ_n(1/n)=nU_{1,n}$. This is the same as $n(1-U_{n,n})$, but for samples $1-U_i$ which are uniformly distributed as well.